# Fitting a model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have a problem with fitting a model in lmer. My DV is reaction time to picture naming which is a continuous variable. I have three IV which are categorical. The first factor is TMS condition: either Vertex or Baseline. The second factor is Age: young or old and my third factor is SOA condition: -300ms, 0ms or +300ms. I do not have the same number of participants under any of the SOA conditions and wanted to collapse the result of all SOA conditions as one condition but also account for any variability that this factor may bring.
But, my formula failed to converge with following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.224029 (tol = 0.002, component 18)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues
```

Here is the formula:

```
test = lmer(Reaction_time ~ TMS_Condition+Age+SOA_Condition + (1+SOA_Condition|Subject)+
                            (1+SOA_Condition|Picture_Name),
            data = F_TMS[F_TMS$Picture_Type=='Target',],)
```

Comment: They are 'warnings' and not 'error' messages.

Comment: @rnso, they are warnings, but "model failed to converge" is something to pay attention to nonetheless.